# How to optimize the ulam spiral infinite iterator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, optimization

I have created an infinite iterator which maps natural numbers to all lattice points in a spiral like manner, akin to the Ulam Spiral:

[image]

The code is below, I have made it as fast as possible, and I didn't use a single if condition:

```
from itertools import islice, repeat

def ulamish_spiral_gen():
    xc = yc = length = 0
    yield 0, 0
    while True:
        length += 1
        yield from zip(range(xc + 1, (xc := xc + length) + 1, 1), repeat(yc))
        yield from zip(repeat(xc), range(yc + 1, (yc := yc + length) + 1, 1))
        length += 1
        yield from zip(range(xc - 1, (xc := xc - length) - 1, -1), repeat(yc))
        yield from zip(repeat(xc), range(yc - 1, (yc := yc - length) - 1, -1))

def ulamish_spiral(n):
    return list(islice(ulamish_spiral_gen(), n))
```

I want to know, how to memoize the output of the infinite iterator, so that `list(islice(ulamish_spiral_gen(), n))` will be called only when the value of `n` is greater than the last `n`.

Something like this:

```
COMPUTED = []

def ulamish_spiral(n):
    global COMPUTED
    if n > len(COMPUTED):
        COMPUTED = list(islice(ulamish_spiral_gen(), n))
    return COMPUTED[:n]
```

It is very easy, but the first `len(COMPUTED)` terms have already been computed, only terms in `range(len(COMPUTED), n)` need to be computed, but the call computes all the already computed terms. So I tried to reuse the same generator object and only ask for the next `n - len(COMPUTED)` items, and I have succeeded.

But doing so actually makes code slower:

```
COMPUTED = []
ULAMISH_GEN = ulamish_spiral_gen()
def ulamish_spiral(n):
    if n > (l := len(COMPUTED)):
        COMPUTED.extend(islice(ULAMISH_GEN, n - l))
    return COMPUTED[:n]
```

```
In [225]: %timeit COMPUTED.clear(); ULAMISH_GEN = ulamish_spiral_gen(); ulamish_spiral(8192)
928 µs ± 8.96 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [226]: %timeit COMPUTED.clear(); ULAMISH_GEN = ulamish_spiral_gen(); ulamish_spiral(1024); ulamish_spiral(2048); ulamish_spiral(4096); ulamish_spiral(8192)
993 µs ± 18.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [227]: %timeit COMPUTED.clear(); ULAMISH_GEN = ulamish_spiral_gen(); ulamish_spiral(1024); ulamish_spiral(2048); ulamish_spiral(4096); ulamish_spiral(8192); ulamish_spiral(16384)
2.14 ms ± 106 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [228]: %timeit COMPUTED.clear(); ULAMISH_GEN = ulamish_spiral_gen(); ulamish_spiral(16384)
2 ms ± 88.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [229]: COMPUTED.clear(); ULAMISH_GEN = ulamish_spiral_gen(); ulamish_spiral(1024); ulamish_spiral(2048); ulamish_spiral(16384) == list(islice(ulamish_spiral_gen(), 16384))
Out[229]: True
```

How can I skip already computed terms and make code faster?

Comment: due to your measurements it does not seem to be considerably slower: you're comparing one call with multiple calls which are equivalent in `n` param.

Comment: *"made it as fast as possible"* - I'm pretty sure I could make it faster :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already covered "memoize"/"skip". Here are faster infinite iterators. Times for the first 16384 coordinates (as in your benchmark):

```
  1.01 ± 0.00 ms  gen_Kelly_4
  1.01 ± 0.00 ms  gen_Kelly_5
  1.03 ± 0.00 ms  gen_Kelly_3
  1.06 ± 0.00 ms  gen_Kelly_2
  1.21 ± 0.00 ms  gen_Kelly_1
  1.57 ± 0.00 ms  gen_original

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Jun 24 2023, 10:18:04) [GCC 13.1.1 20230429]
```

You combine all the `zip` iterators with your own generator. My `gen_Kelly_1` instead uses `chain.from_iterable` for that.

You use the `range` function to produce the `int` objects over and over again. My `gen_Kelly_2` instead keeps them in a list and reuses them.

My `gen_Kelly_3` further reuses the `repeat` iterators, `gen_Kelly_4` reverses my list instead of using reverse iterators, and `gen_Kelly_5` removes the now duplicated code (`i` goes through 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, etc):

```
def gen_Kelly_5():
    def parts():
        i = 0
        range = []
        while True:
            rep = repeat(i)
            yield zip(rep, range)
            range.append(i)
            range.reverse()
            yield zip(range, rep)
            i = (i<1) - i
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())
```

Full code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=zVfNbptAEL6jPsRKPXhpsGViJ4pQOfXYS6X25loIw2CvCgvaXdLQKE_SSy7tvY_QPkafpvsDGOK_xEmqcEDs7MzsN9-3wOz3n0UlVjm9vf1RimR48ffV74TlGRIkAyIQyYqciXpk6RkuQkG4IBFvZjMIqSPtMVwaFyKAiTxPWw_CUxKBgxgUEAoHRVWUymG0ComMjPKSCqt25RW3rBgStAQa5IwsCQ1TbHsWktdVhHxUqVsKdClW8mGsJyoCaYzGTj38uiIpoE-sBBOnrjrixEduazNhGvM3UmAW0iVgucgJch2kHjwf6aEJts2EazeV4Cqy7Z3ZjMtVpNx15qrJXOnM1ZbM9lF4h328wzarnhg-BvCwD3gztW2t9XoPaVoFbiOXMhchE7wx7NVwjQgrIW2ntW6TcxdF6yxPoOidZI8T9IGIj9T0HpDvIanKwkCUjJqXdKQ2SaDe63CRAq5F3ZT-dK_0pKe1xiMts_lBoTcKGhJd_iUwDrHh7A4H2jYilMtPkdpPMmIf4y2Z0q_vSPaqZYJIQ-82DGFRAI3x7vX7ZbRIyCN0mDyPDhKZdFwztZuVZ1DnoCw9dAfAPaVYx8s0fQEyHWDibriZrGnAL1q146Aeo-PZf9DxBVDTLQiTt676Y5AHkJaUVHaNfq-1c7qNQ3dw2h1MuoNpd3BmWVSmdM8nF1PLeo3e5YxBJChwbsFVIR9VpyEbVmyaUKxBzMZzLF9eKmElOUMJIhSZCdebe3VJvEw3gpso5RFy9flqHX1k1lMoPhYAsaXaZlXvdeJJuVF_pRu9h1Q3zXFS7xahvGcCvUEuTLS_UP5cNsbyk6PTzZK5PfPc8XzeJT4ZXKsuHAtue-ej0-QG_fmFrnVLrm1Tbcs4Guh6A5XV9APueDyuV-_jW29FRYI5AeA0zBZx6G3lRN7KbAHMd9e7pYHcbEPR4buuSi_moC9Q-ZqMGkzBCBW4ocdBySgIaJhBENiWmRt8ph_02cUbOOrYMFKbmeTUNieZ-kDTHGz-AQ)):

```py
from timeit import timeit
from statistics import mean, stdev
from itertools import islice, repeat, cycle, chain, count
import sys

def gen_original():
    xc = yc = length = 0
    yield 0, 0
    while True:
        length += 1
        yield from zip(range(xc + 1, (xc := xc + length) + 1, 1), repeat(yc))
        yield from zip(repeat(xc), range(yc + 1, (yc := yc + length) + 1, 1))
        length += 1
        yield from zip(range(xc - 1, (xc := xc - length) - 1, -1), repeat(yc))
        yield from zip(repeat(xc), range(yc - 1, (yc := yc - length) - 1, -1))


def gen_Kelly_1():
    def parts():
        xc = yc = length = 0
        yield (0, 0),
        while True:
            length += 1
            yield zip(range(xc + 1, (xc := xc + length) + 1, 1), repeat(yc))
            yield zip(repeat(xc), range(yc + 1, (yc := yc + length) + 1, 1))
            length += 1
            yield zip(range(xc - 1, (xc := xc - length) - 1, -1), repeat(yc))
            yield zip(repeat(xc), range(yc - 1, (yc := yc - length) - 1, -1))
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())


def gen_Kelly_2():
    def parts():
        i = 0
        range = []
        while True:
            yield zip(repeat(-i), reversed(range))
            range.insert(0, -i)
            yield zip(range, repeat(-i))
            i += 1
            yield zip(repeat(i), range)
            range.append(i)
            yield zip(reversed(range), repeat(i))
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())


def gen_Kelly_3():
    def parts():
        i = 0
        range = []
        while True:
            rep = repeat(-i)
            yield zip(rep, reversed(range))
            range.insert(0, -i)
            yield zip(range, rep)
            i += 1
            rep = repeat(i)
            yield zip(rep, range)
            range.append(i)
            yield zip(reversed(range), rep)
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())


def gen_Kelly_4():
    def parts():
        i = 0
        range = []
        while True:
            rep = repeat(-i)
            yield zip(rep, range)
            range.append(-i)
            range.reverse()
            yield zip(range, rep)
            i += 1
            rep = repeat(i)
            yield zip(rep, range)
            range.append(i)
            range.reverse()
            yield zip(range, rep)
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())


def gen_Kelly_5():
    def parts():
        i = 0
        range = []
        while True:
            rep = repeat(i)
            yield zip(rep, range)
            range.append(i)
            range.reverse()
            yield zip(range, rep)
            i = (i<1) - i
    return chain.from_iterable(parts())


funcs = gen_original, gen_Kelly_1, gen_Kelly_2, gen_Kelly_3, gen_Kelly_4, gen_Kelly_5

n = 16384

# Correctness
expect = list(islice(funcs[0](), n))
for f in funcs[1:]:
    result = list(islice(f(), n))
    assert result == expect

# Speed
times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:10]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '
for _ in range(1000):
    for f in funcs:
        t = timeit(lambda: list(islice(f(), n)), number=1)
        times[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

Comment: I expected that using `yield from` would be faster than using `chain.from_iterable` but when I ran the benchmark your version was almost 50% faster.  I expected that `yield from` would use some magically fast opcode, but `dis` shows I was wrong (at least for CPython 3.11).  interesting post!  any idea/pointers to why CPython has this behaviour?

Comment: @SamMason Sorry, I don't know the implementation details enough to explain it. I just know from experience (like this one) over that last few years/versions that `chain` adds **much** less overhead than `yield from`. I just tried again, `chain` added about 0.9 ns per element while `yield from` added about 20.6 ns per element. See code in next comment.

Comment: [Code](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVNLTsMwEF2wyylmV7syIUGogkg9SVVFbjMGi8QJzqRSVfUkbLqBPVfgGJwG20noRwgRKQvPvHnz3oz9-t5s6ak2h8NbR-r6_uvqStm6AtIVagJdNbWl4RSFTEuSdEt63Y7ZCqURLl7gpoes67LENena_GAKfOkwGg6a0FJdl20UFaig6SwyH5OrEnkWgfssUmcNjNEeuNVYFrlvcQkPGQjNz0vWT1KbP8iDjPgCdVKab7TMx8T_eGIv41jzUyS4I1adcYObB8_ixJDo24lfukaRH78v2qkMFktQtQUF2kAg2wexfistU4Mw8ugFwRRSfAh48vjWDR8LFugWaskXWZosl6dW1GTnt8mo5dksvlV7-PyAXVhtiN2FmFvrxFlxtLmntdI8IkuTZOh-rq-PBVVOVH-TWCmrVSGz_lowxY4jtNigJJYISJPpdMa5gMT9pqtWaOcphxvnaXbkHLzEsmnQOG-8F6ZO_AYZAp5xOw9jGmQ2Vhti4-AEqDjPjawwz3n_FoYnMT6Nbw)

Comment: @SamMason Actually, 0.9 ns is suspiciously fast, given that that's just a few clock cycles on a modern CPU with ~3 GHz and given the work that the iterator has to do for each element. But I think I did that correctly. I guess I just don't understand modern CPUs anymore...

Comment: What you did looks right, but am away from a real computer for a bit so can't check.  Neat test framework, haven't thought of using `timeit` like that!  Think I'd just report quantiles rather than standard deviation, but maybe that's just me.

Comment: @SamMason How would it look with quantiles? Note I'm not really interested in the stdev, I mainly use it as indication (when the stdev is low) that the script had a stable run (especially since I'm running it on that shared service site) so that I'm more confident about the mean (which is the value I *am* interested in).

Comment: I mentioned that because you're calculating the mean/SD of the fastest 10% of runs.  Why not just directly report the runtime from indexes `0, 5, 10` from the sorted array?  These correspond to the 0%, 5%, and 10% quantiles (i.e. the values are implicitly sorted).  A standard deviation of 0.0 gets me worried that something might have gone wrong, seeing values lets a reader see what's going on.  Hopefully that makes some sense!

Comment: Comments are kind of awkward for describing this

Comment: @SamMason I don't like showing multiple times, I think that would be confusing for the reader. Then I'd have to explain what they mean, or they'd have to read the benchmarking code. I had shown multiple times (though not quantiles) before ending up with my current format and didn't like it, for that reason. I much prefer to show just a single time, and an indication that that single time is trustworthy. Similar to what timeit's CLI does ("best of 5") and what IPython's %timeit does (like "8.26 ns ± 0.12 ns per loop [...]"). The 0.00 here is a rare exception, maybe I should've used fewer runs.

Comment: (I usually use 25 or 100 runs, here I used 1000 because the OP had provided their own benchmarking with limit n=16384, so I used the same limit, and it was so fast that 1000 runs don't take long.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a "cutting the knot" solution, but if you really need performance, you might consider ditching iterators so you can use `numba` and `numpy`.

```py
from itertools import repeat
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

def ulamish_spiral_gen():
    xc = yc = length = 0
    yield 0, 0
    while True:
        length += 1
        yield from zip(range(xc + 1, (xc := xc + length) + 1, 1), repeat(yc))
        yield from zip(repeat(xc), range(yc + 1, (yc := yc + length) + 1, 1))
        length += 1
        yield from zip(range(xc - 1, (xc := xc - length) - 1, -1), repeat(yc))
        yield from zip(repeat(xc), range(yc - 1, (yc := yc - length) - 1, -1))

@njit
def spiral_noiter(len_):
    # Based on Julia code from Peter Luschny on OEIS.
    # https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Peter_Luschny
    # See https://oeis.org/A174344
    x, y, i, j, N, n, c = np.int64(0), np.int64(0), np.int8(0), np.int8(0), np.int64(0), np.int64(0), np.int8(0)
    res = np.empty(len_, dtype="i,i")
    for k in range(len_):
        res[k][0] = x
        res[k][1] = -y
        if n == 0:
            c = (c+1)%4
            i = (c&1)*(-(c&2)+1)
            j = ((~c)&1)*(((~c)&2)-1)
            N += c&1
            n = N
        n -= 1
        x += i
        y += j
    return res

n = 16384
```

Here are the results I got.

```py
In [3]: %timeit spiral_noiter(n)
11.2 µs ± 5.56 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: %timeit list(islice(ulamish_spiral_gen(),n))
1.02 ms ± 16.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Returns a different result (type) though, right? Which would be slower to then use in Python (unless you use numba/numpy for that as well).

Comment: @KellyBundy It would definitely be slow to convert the resulting `numpy` array to a list of Python `int` tuples, yes. (It looks like it brings us back to around 1 ms on my machine.) I don't know the actual application here, but it seems plausible that the rest of the code could use `numpy` types instead of Python types with only limited changes. If you need bignums, for example, you might still need to convert. I don't think it's likely the rest of the code would need to use `numba`, though.